# How to pass HashMap to forEach tag in xls generated by jett?

Tags: java, collections, foreach, hashmap, jett

I have a Map in managed bean

```
    private Map<FaseProducao, Set<FichaTecnicaOperacao>> fichasTecnicasOperacaoResumo;
```

that reference to entity FichaTecnica:

```
public class FichaTecnica{
//...
    private Set<FichaTecnicaOperacao> operacoes;
}
```

which I need to pass as a parameter on a beans.put () to generate an xls with jett:

```
public void createRelatorioFichaTecnica(FichaTecnica fichaTecnica) throws IOException {
    //ommited...
    Map<String, Object> beans = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    beans.put("operacaoResumo", fichasTecnicasOperacaoResumo);

    try (ByteArrayOutputStream saida = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            InputStream template = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/templates/jett/fichaTecnica.xls");
            Workbook workbook = transformer.transform(template, beans);) {
            //ommited...
            }
}
```

when the xls is generated the exception happens:

```
WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (default task-28) #{ProdutoManagedBean.createRelatorioFichaTecnica(row)}: net.sf.jett.exception.AttributeExpressionException: Expected a "java.util.Collection" for "items", got a "java.util.HashMap":  "${operacaoResumo}".
```

so I'm not understanding this error because a Map is a correct collection? So why does not jett recognize it in items = "$ {operacaoResumo}"? I created this forEach based on the link on the site:
http://jett.sourceforge.net/tags/forEach.html

Comment: `java.util.Map` is **not** a `java.util.Collection`, they are entirely separate interfaces.

Comment: You probably want to do `beans.put(YOUR_KEY, yourMap.values())`.

Comment: Actually, when I debug beans.put("operacaoResumo", fichasTecnicasOperacaoResumo);
the values come correctly, and I need to pass that complete map to the forEach items = "$ {operacaoResumo}" in the jett because I need the key FaseProducao. Any idea how I can do this? @daniu

Comment: You could pass the `EntrySet` of the map: `beans.put("operacaoResumo", fichasTechicasOperacaoResumo.keySet());`, which is a `Collection` (specifically, a `Set`).  Use `getKey()` and `getValue()` to access your key and value in the template.

Comment: @rgettman That worked! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @rgettman said I did:

```
public void createRelatorioFichaTecnica(FichaTecnica fichaTecnica) throws IOException {
    //ommited...
    Map<String, Object> beans = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    beans.put("operacaoResumo", fichasTechicasOperacaoResumo.keySet());

}
```

thank you all!